# Initialize VSS.SDK from TS class

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to initialize the VSS.SDK from a .ts class (outside the html page). I have analyzed some examples from Microsoft and all are initialize under html page.Is it possible to do this outside html page?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this link for details: [Visual Studio Services Web Extension SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk).

> **Types**
>
> - Types of VSS.SDK.js, controls and client services are available in    typings/vss.d.ts.
> - REST Client types for VSTS are available in    typings/tfs.d.ts
> - REST Client and extensibility types for Release    Management are available in typings/rmo.d.ts

**Using tsd**

Although TypeScript declare files do not exist at DefinitelyTyped repo, they can still be used through tsd.

1. First, make sure that the dependencies are loaded using below
   command:

   tsd install jquery knockout q --save
2. Next, run below command to get
   vss-web-extension-sdk types added to tsd.d.ts:

   tsd link
3. Finally, add only reference to typings/tsd.d.ts in your
   TypeScript files.

Comment: What is tsd?  Is that like npm?  It is not mentioned at the link you provided.

Comment: I guess you meant npm, and just wrote tsd by accident.  Can you explain how you determined how to do this?  This is not explained at the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could to do it outside the html and put it in the JavaScript file or other (e.g. ts), then add the reference to corresponding JS file to the html page.

For example:

```
    VSS.init();
$(document).ready(function () {
    VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();

});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello word</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/VSS.SDK.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/VSSInit.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript">
        VSS.init();
    </script>-->

    <h1>Hello word</h1>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript">
        VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
    </script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Starain,
The issue is my extension is a build task, it does not have any html page. When I try to init VSS.SDK from typescript it throw an error telling window object is not found since I'm trying to load it outside of browser. All I want to do is push some build summary to vss extension data service. Do you have any alternatives for this?